# breathing techniques in buddhism

Tags: technique

My name is Prakash Karki. I am from Nepal. . I have just read 1 book on buddhisam and that is biography and philosophy of buddha. I became very serious about this spiritual stuff. I have been researching about spirituality for 2 years now. I want to know about the journey. how to be more serious about it and what should I do at first step as a beginner ?

Comment: Is your question about Buddhism in general or about breathing techniques in Buddhism?

Comment: I mean both of them. This is my first question I have ever asked so I cannot articulate my thoughts. I am improving day by day.

Answer (score 1):

Where to begin and how to start...

For the sake of being concise, you already are on the path because you're kicking brother. Have you heard of the butterfly effect? Your actions, intentions and responses reflect the dynamic of the environment around you (family, work, etc) and so on and so forth.
That's the beginning to the whole 'spiritual stuff'.

Some breathing techniques that I have found useful (not only buddhist):

- Tummo (buddhist)
- Freediving
- Yoga (breathing into the pressure to release the tension)

Cultivate in Harmony

Comment: thank you soo much.

Comment: Anytime! Just remember to keep a humble mind during the initial stages of self experimentation and you'll make the most from self discovery. 
Understanding the foundations of a technique comes from the memory of the body as well as the thought of mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should do a goenka retreat goenka is powerful and it's donation based I know it's powerful because a women did suicide because of going there  becoming the only meditation retreat that did irreversible damage like that so be careful and 1,2 millions people did goenka 10 days retreat till now it's the most popular meditation retreat and the most powerful it exists in 90+ countries  many people did have a good experience there you can just google them

It teachs breathing technique and body scan method I recommend you to download their app  and play the mini anapana/breathing guided meditation ->
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vipassanameditation just follow the audio instructions there, you can also search and apply the nearest 10 day meditation retreat using the app

But for a breathing theory you can read https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/WithEachAndEveryBreath/Section0007.html this thanissaro bhikku is the one who translated suttas from pali to english you can call him the modern buddha if you want because he knows nearly the entire suttas so you don't need to read that thousands suttas to only understand buddha's meditation/right concentration

Answer (score -1):

The Buddha did not teaching any breathing technique.

In Buddhism, the mind is made empty of craving. When the mind is empty of craving, the breathing becomes the natural automatic object of consciousness.

Breathing techniques is Hinduism rather than Buddhism.

Comment: Buddha most probably did not teach breathing techniques. He mentioned breathing and attention to breathing in MN 118, which might be helpful..